# google_play_services_version does not have the right value

Tags: android, frameworks, google-play

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.more.thirdcom.gp/com.clash.of.kings.EmpireActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value. Expected 12451000 but found 4323000. You must have the following declaration within the  element:

Comment: I personally think that this problem occurs because the SDK version is inconsistent. But what is the value of 4323000 obtained, which version? I want to know this too.

Comment: Can you reproduce this crash?

Comment: yes, 1 Answer is the crash.@JohnNimis